# Extend an regex with logical AND in a non-capturing group

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to extend an existing regex string:

`((?:street)|(?:addr)|(?:straße)|(?:strasse)|(?:adr))`

It basically matches strings like street or address.
So now I want to add, that if the strings 'addressAdd' or 'streetnr' exists it doesn't match anything anymore (not even street).

I tried
`((?:street)|(?:addr)|(?:straße)|(?:strasse)|(?:adr))(^(?:addressAdd))(^(?:streetnr))`
and several variations thereof however didn't succeed. Does anyone of you know how to negate strings?

**Update**: Some clarification: If a string like `addressAdd` exists I don't want that any string matches. The java code for this would look like this:

```
String toCheck="some string to match";
if((!toCheck.equals("streetnr") && !toCheck.equals("addressAdd")) && ( toCheck.equals("street") || toCheck.equals("strasse") || toCheck.equals("adr"))
```

Comment: What are all those non-capturing groups for?!

Comment: replace `(?:street)` with `\bstreet\b` likewise add `\b` for all the substrings if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather remove unnecessary grouping constructs and add a negative lookahead with these 2 exceptions:

```
(?!addressAdd|streetnr)(?:street|addr|straße|strasse|adr)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP0iX8/1)

To match whole words:

```
\b(?!(?:addressAdd|streetnr)\b)(?:street|addr|straße|strasse|adr)\b
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN2fB7/1)

Here, you can read more about [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In short: `(?!addressAdd|streetnr)` checks if there is no `addressAdd` and `streetnr` after the current position and only then the regex engine can go on matching one of the alternatives listed in `(?:street|addr|straße|strasse|adr)` non-capturing group. With word boundaries (`\b(?!(?:addressAdd|streetnr)\b)`) only those exceptions are skipped that are whole words (so, if there is `streetnrs`, it will get matched).

**Answer to the update:**
To match strings (or lines if `DOTALL` option is not used) that contain specific substrings and do not contain disallowed *whole* words, use the negative lookahead at the beginning of the pattern right after `^`:

```
^(?!.*\b(?:addressAdd|streetnr)\b).*(?:street|addr|straße|strasse|adr).*
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ4mT3/1)

Comment: Thanks that is one part, but the behaviour I need is that none of the string matches (anymore) if "addressAdd" or "streetnr" exists. So it can basically abort the rest of the checking if one of the strings appears...

Comment: Do you mean you do not want to obtain the string that *contains* `addressAdd` or `streetnr`? It is much easier, but to give a 100% safe recommendation, I'd need to know what the regex flavor it. You can always try [`^(?!.*\b(?:addressAdd|streetnr)\b).+`](https://regex101.com/r/yU1iL3/1).

Comment: the combination of that and the first post works -thanks alot!